# Выполнять функцию при изменении значения (крон задача)

Tags: wordpress, cron

уважаемые специалисты.

Хочу добавить в cron задачу с выполнением каждые 5 минут. И при изменении значения количества комментариев в WordPress

```
$comments_count = wp_count_comments( );

$comments_count->approved
```

чтобы выполнилась функция (очистка кэша). Как это можно реализовать?